# free pointer to array?

Tags: objective-c

I have inside my objective c function, a line that do this :

```
    for(int k=0;k<numOfBuffers;k++)
{

 float *temp=getFFT(buffersRing[k],buffersRing[k][0]);
......// do stuff with temp
```

the fft function gives back pointer to array of 512 floats

```
float* getFFT(int16_t *q, int bufferL)
```

my questions :

1. inside the function that defines `*temp` over and over again ,do i need to later `free` all temp pointers, or they auto gone outside that function ?
2. if i want to free this space INSIDE that function after the `for loop` anyway , how would i do that (in code... )
   thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `temp` itself is an automatic variable inside the function; it will disappear when the function exits.

The memory the `temp` pointer *points at*, however, will not automatically be de-allocated.

You must know whether the `getFFT()` function expects the caller to free the memory or not. This can be implemented in either way and it's not clear from the API you shown.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you need to free the memory pointed to by temp explicitly otherwise you will have a memory leak.
2. You will have to move the declaration of temp out of the loop to be abel to free the memory pointed to by it outside the loop.

Comment: so right now i have declared many pointers- so i can't free them all? is it took too much memory ? the temp pointer is not deallocated automatically outside the function ? , i did took it out of the for loop, and than freed it, but i would like to know how much memory will it take from me if i am not free it ..

Comment: Leaking memory is never a good option. Even if the memory consumed seems little, with time it will build on and eventually it will eat up all your RAM.